# Type error: Module '"@solana/spl-token"' has no exported member 'createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction'

Tags: spl-token

I am getting this on all functions inside @solana/spl-token

Answer (score 1):

The recent versions of `@solana/spl-token` package don't have this instruction in it.

You can make it like this:

```
import { web3 } from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID } from "@solana/spl-token";
import { SPL_ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_ACCOUNT_PROGRAM_ID } from "../constants/programIds";

export function createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
  associatedTokenAddress: web3.PublicKey,
  payer: web3.PublicKey,
  walletAddress: web3.PublicKey,
  splTokenMintAddress: web3.PublicKey
) {
  const keys = [
    {
      pubkey: payer,
      isSigner: true,
      isWritable: true,
    },
    {
      pubkey: associatedTokenAddress,
      isSigner: false,
      isWritable: true,
    },
    {
      pubkey: walletAddress,
      isSigner: false,
      isWritable: false,
    },
    {
      pubkey: splTokenMintAddress,
      isSigner: false,
      isWritable: false,
    },
    {
      pubkey: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      isSigner: false,
      isWritable: false,
    },
    {
      pubkey: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      isSigner: false,
      isWritable: false,
    },
    {
      pubkey: web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
      isSigner: false,
      isWritable: false,
    },
  ];

  return new web3.TransactionInstruction({
    keys,
    programId: SPL_ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_ACCOUNT_PROGRAM_ID,
    data: Buffer.from([]),
  });
}
```